# python find matches from a list

Tags: python, list

I am new to python, i am trying to search ad get all matched items from a list in python, however i am not getting if my input is case sensitive compared with List items.

The code which i am trying is below

```
# dl is available items in the list
dl=['AA_Food', 'FOOD_ORDER', 'AA_FOOD_APP', 'HOTPATH', 'FO_HOT', 'TEST_FOOD']
# search items 
r = re.compile(".*FOO.*")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, dl)) # Read Note
nl = json.dumps(newlist)
print(nl)
```

I am getting the below result:

```
["FOOD_ORDER", "AA_FOOD_APP", "TEST_FOOD"]
```

But the expected result is:

```
["AA_Food", "FOOD_ORDER", "AA_FOOD_APP", "TEST_FOOD"]
```

please help.

Comment: As a note, for something like this you don't need a regex at all. You can just do `newlist = list(filter(lambda x: x.find('FOO') != -1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `re.IGNORECASE` for this

```
import re

# dl is available items in the list
dl=['AA_Food', 'FOOD_ORDER', 'AA_FOOD_APP', 'HOTPATH', 'FO_HOT', 'TEST_FOOD']
# search items 
r = re.compile(".*FOO.*", re.IGNORECASE)
newlist = list(filter(r.match, dl)) # Read Note
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be because in the expression you have strictly defined `FOO` to be uppercase. Try using `(FOO|Foo)` in place of `FOO`.

Hopefully, it works for you.

Comment: Zahim Hassan: both logics works well. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I dont see why you need to use regular expressions. This can be done simply by using list comprehension

```
new_list = [item for item in dl if "foo" in item.lower()]
```